# Access parent controller methods from directive?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-services

I have a question with some page about item search.

Let's say I have:

1. A **controller** with **result items to display**
2. A **service** that performs the search queries and interacts to the controller so it updates the **result items to display**
3. A **directive** which has the **form** with all the inputs of the search fields.

One of the buttons is a "View more items" button. It should only be shown if the response that I receive from a query tells me that there are more items to view.

I made a function inside the **service** which checks this property and returns a boolean to the **directive** which uses it with a ng-show on the button to show or hide it.

The problem is that I don't know how to interact with the **controller** within this scope.

Should the **directive** call one **service method** and this method should interact with the **controller** in some way?

Before this I was wrapping the directive with a form tag (outside the directive's scope) and then I could use the ng-submit to perform some action on the **controller** to call the **service**. Like this:

```
<form ng-submit="myController.submitSearch">
    <search-options-directive></search-options-directive>
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

But now what I'm trying to do is to put the form and the buttons inside the

```
<search-options-directive></search-options-directive>
```

So now I don't have access to call **controller** methods directly.

How should I approach this?

Comment: That sounds like a prime example for the "require" option on your search-directive - in short: create an outer directive whose controller is the "item display controller". Then you can require the outer directive in the search-directive and voila, you have access to the controller directly. Here is some reference for the compile service which specifies require: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: The other answer is probably better but there is the `scope.$parent` property too.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a bit more specific to your title, "Access parent controller methods from directive." Within your directive you'll have to add the method that you want to share:

```
return {
   scope: {
     myFavoriteMethod:'&'
   }
}
```

Then on:

```
<search-options-directive my-favorite-method="myMethodOnTheParentController"></search-options-directive>
```

In your directive you'll need to add to your html:

```
 ng-click="myFavoriteMethod()"
```

But in your example you're using a ng-submit button which binds the expression to onsubmit event (overriding the original submit action), which is different from ng-click, but you should be able to use the same pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What I really want to know is the best practice to do what I want, since I don't know the approach to take since it seems that I have 3 very co-dependent elements.

Comment: The best practice is going to follow basic tenements encapsulation etc. For this I would recommend moving into it's own directive as you have started to do, and then modify my example to use ng-submit instead of ng-click.

Comment: Any by tenements I didn't mean housing, whoops!

Comment: @Jeffarese did this work for you, where you able to apply it to your needs?

Comment: This way I can not use this-pointer in called method (parent controller). It always uses directive this.

Comment: @ndee Yes the idea is to isolate your pieces. Your service however can be reached from both the directive and your controller. What is the specific method in your controller trying to do that your directive needs to call?

From rereading this it seems like your title and your body are two slightly different questions, perhaps you can refine your question and I can better help you.